# How does the | affect a BNF grammar?

Tags: bnf

I'm working on a school project that requires me to parse a BNF grammar. I'm a little confused as to what role the pipe character (|) - which I believe means "or" - plays in a rule.

For example, if I had the following:

```
<a> ::= b c d | e f g
```

Which of the terminals is the | applied to? Using parentheses for grouping, which would describe how the "or" is applied?

> **(b c d)** | **(e f g)**
>
> (b c) **(d)** | **(e)** (f g)

Is the | applied to the entire set of terminals, or just the two next to the |?

And what if I had a set up like:

```
<a> ::= b | <c> <d>
<b> ::= e | f
<c> ::= g | h
```

Would it still be true if `<c>` and `<d>` refer to non-terminals? To what would the | be applied in this case?

Comment: And finally a meaningful non-n00b question on StackOverflow! Definitely +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general,

```
rule := a b c | d e f
```

is grouped as

```
rule := (a b c) | (d e f)
```

This doesn't change whether or not you apply them to terminals or non-terminals.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for, and I was able to get my assignment done correctly and on time.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

You can view | as the lowest precedence operator.